# Changing a field in mysql using mysql cmd line

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get more familiar with using command line.. so i'm kind of new.

How would i update this field 'value' from 1 to 0?

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path = 'web/seo/use_rewrites'
    -> ;
+-----------+---------+----------+----------------------+-------+
| config_id | scope   | scope_id | path                 | value |
+-----------+---------+----------+----------------------+-------+
|        18 | default |        0 | web/seo/use_rewrites | 1     |
+-----------+---------+----------+----------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

I tried this update statement but it didn't work:

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value='0' WHERE config_id=18;
```

I threw this error in command line:

**ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHEREc WHERE config_id=18' at line 1**

Comment: Looks OK to me. Hmmm. !! :S

Comment: @GurV I got this error: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHEREc WHERE config_id=18' at line 1

Comment: How do you know your `update` query didn't work? Please [edit] your question to let us know as precisely as you can how you know this. I ask because your statement looks correct to me.

Comment: **`WHEREc WHERE config_id=18`** -- Error clearly shows that the query you executed is not the same as you posted in the question.

Comment: weird... i tried it again and it worked. .. not sure how that happened.